# Sleep and Threading (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying the following code from a threading example in Ruby:

```
count = 0
arr = []

10.times do |i|
  arr[i] = Thread.new {
  sleep(count*10)
  Thread.current["mycount"] = count
  count += 1
}
end

arr.each {|t| t.join; print t["mycount"], ", " }
puts "count = #{count}"
```

Because I increase the sleep on each thread, I expect the output to be in order from 1-10, 
However in almost all runs, the order is random. Why ?

Comment: use a ruby queue if you want a synchronized collection, and your question is not clear on what you intend to achieve, you can find documentation on ruby queue at http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/Queue.html

Answer (score 1):

You are only updating `count` after the thread finishes sleeping, so all of the threads read the initial value of `count`, which is 0, when they go to sleep.

It's also worth noting that accessing `count` in this way is not threadsafe.

Comment: Thanks! So when I put the sleep after, I usually get the result in order which is what I was looking for ! However occasionally it is STILL out of order, is this because I don't put synchronization on my count ?

Comment: Yes, the threads are not guaranteed to run in the order you started them. If you want this invariant, you should use explicit synchronization primitives, so one of the later-numbered threads could read the smaller value of count. In this case, you will *probably* get the result you want by moving the "count * 10" computation out of the thread block. But relying on this is perilous.

Answer (score 0):

The order is random because the access of the object `count` is not synchronized amongst threads.

You are encountering what is called a Race Condition

> A race condition occurs when two or more threads can access shared data and they try to change it at the same time.

You can stop this through using mutex, condition variables and queue objects within ruby.

**EDIT:** Also, see Jeremy's answer

Comment: This is fine, and I think the purpose of this example is to demonstrate threading without synchronization. Shouldn't synchronization be psuedo-fixed by just putting an increasing sleep timer on each thread?

Comment: I guess in theory the majority of the time that would be true, BUT as you've seen, it's not always true in reality!  There's always the possibility another thread could sneak in. It's not something you should rely on.  Synchronisation is best and you can be fully confident that your solution works. A Queue object would be best, in Ruby it has synchronisation built in if I recall correctly